# Alternative to pd.rolling for older versions of pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of size 10000 rows (scenarios( × 900 columns (time in month). The data is log returns in monthly terms, but I want to get annual returns. I tried

```
df_data_zero.rolling(12, min_periods=12, axis = 1).sum()
```

But I get the error "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'rolling'". I guess it has to do with my pandas version (0.13.1). Any solution that does not involve updating pandas? Thank you!

Comment: Why would you not want to update pandas? 0.13 is ancient (released in 2014)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For older pandas versions maybe this will work:

```
pd.rolling_sum(df_data_zero, window=12, min_periods=12)
```